# How to protect home LAN when using OpenVPN to connect to remote LAN?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, remote-desktop, openvpn

I have a home network (a router, PCs, phones, smart devices, etc.). I'd like to connect from this home LAN to a remote LAN at my work via OpenVPN (which is what our IT provides there). The remote LAN is large, with transient semi-random users, lax security and a zoo of software.

How can I setup VPN connection (almost exclusively for RDP) to this LAN on a single PC at home, while making sure my home devices are protected from possible threats originating from there?

Answer (score 0):

Install a firewall on the device in your network that terminates the VPN-connection. Configure this firewall to block all incoming connections coming thru the VPN, and only allow connections from your network to the VPN.